# How to Import files from another folder in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to import files from another folder, try so many things, but my attempt is not fruitful. How to resolve it?

```
-> d:
   -> project Main
      -> First Folder
         -> my_main_file.py
            -> class (My_Main_Class)
               -> module1
               -> module2
               -> module3
      -> Second Folder 
         -> my_second_file.py
```

How to import module1 and module 3 from my first file(my_main_file.py)  into my _second_file.py

**My_main_file**
This is my main file('d:/project_main/main folder'). now I want to import modules "establish_connection_general and other things to my second file. ( d:/project_main/second_folder)

```
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QMessageBox,QApplication
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

    import sqleet
    import os
    import sys
    print("1234567890aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
    
    file_path_general = r"d:\project makeeasy\assist"
    db_name_general = (os.path.join(file_path_general,'makeeasy_general.me'))
    
    passkey_general = "1234"
    new_passkey_general = "1234"
    
    show_errormsg = "show"
    
    
    class Database_connection(QWidget):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super(). __init__()
            self.establish_connection_general()
            # self.cahnge_passkey()
    
        def establish_connection_general(self):
            try:
                connection_general = sqleet.connect(db_name_general,key = passkey_general)
                print("open scueffully")
            except Exception as e:
                if show_errormsg == "show":
                    self.handle_error(e)
                else:
                    pass
    
    
        def cahnge_passkey(self):
            try:
                general_connection = sqleet.connect(db_name_general,key = passkey_general)
                general_connection.change_key(new_passkey_general)
                print("new pass key sucessfully changed")
                general_connection.close()
    
            except Exception as e:
                if show_errormsg == "show":
                    self.handle_error(e)
                else:
                    pass
    
        def handle_error(self,error):
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            filenamewithpath = exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
            head,tail = os.path.split((filenamewithpath))
            lineno = exc_traceback.tb_lineno
            name = exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_name
            type = exc_type.__name__
            message = exc_value
            nl = '\n'
            kk = f'File Name : {tail[:-3]}{nl}'\
                 f'Line No. : {lineno}{nl}'\
                 f'Type : {type}{nl}'\
                 f'Name : {name}{nl}'
            self.msg = QMessageBox()
            self.msg.setFixedSize(1600,400)
            self.msg.setWindowTitle("  Error/Bugs Information")
            self.msg.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon\close006.png'))
            fd = "                                                                           "
            self.msg.setText(f'{type} - {lineno}{fd}')
            self.msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            self.msg.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.Ok)
            self.msg.setInformativeText("")
            self.msg.setDetailedText(kk)
            self.msg.show()
    
    def main():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = Database_connection()
        app.setStyle("Fusion")
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: I don't understand the structure of your code file. Will you give some example code for `my_main_file.py`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, add my main file

Comment: and what do you want to import into `my_second_file`?

Comment: On a side note, what are the things you have listed as `module1`, `module2`, and `module3` in terms of the code you posted. You cannot define modules inside a class as your tree diagram implies. In python, modules are directories and files.

Comment: I think, i treat function as a module (establish connection genral and change passkey)

Comment: Terminology: `establish_connection_general()` is a function, not a module.

Comment: ok done, correct my term and thanks t

Comment: With that said, you can only import names which are declared at the top level of a file. You can import the class `Database_connection`, but you cannot import individiual functions from that class.

Comment: Now after starting to type this up as an answer, I'm starting to wonder if you really want to "import" here. This word has a specific meaning in Python, but I think you mean something else. Can you give more context about what you are trying to do? What do you have in `my_second_file` that needs this class and its functions?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. How to create a connection in another file, by using this code. IS it Possible to create a connection or change the structure?

Comment: Yes, to create a new connection, use an import like Hariharan's answer. Then create an instance and use it the exact same way you already do in `main()`. However, if you need to reuse the same class instance you already created in `main()`, then you have to do something different.

Answer (score 3):

in `my_second_file.py`

```py
from First_Folder.my_main_file import My_Main_Class
```

After Your comment:

```py
from First_Folder.my_main_file import ex(your class object)
```

In your second file

```py
ex.module1()
ex.module3()
```

Comment: How to import my modules from my first file, thats my problem @code-Apprentice

Comment: @tckraomuqnt What do you mean by "modules"? You cannot have "modules" inside a class.

Comment: `ex.module1()` won't work here. Since `ex` is a class and `module1()` is not a static method, you have to create an instance of the class first: `x = My_Main_Class()`.